# Add extra fields when creating relation

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have two tables. One is Product, one is Document (instruction manuals, brochures, etc).

Each product can have many Documents, and a Document may be assigned to many products.

```
Product
    private static $many_many = [
        "Documents" => Document::class,
    ];

Document
    private static $belongs_many_many = [
        "Products" => Product::class
    ];
```

I also need extra fields (for arbitrary business logic reasons) so Product has

```
    private static $many_many_extraFields = [
        'Documents' => [
            'DisplayOrder' => 'Int',
            'DisplayedField' => 'Varchar(100)'
        ]
    ];
```

And it all works ok. When I open the Product tab on a ModelAdmin, I get the relation edit search form and it writes a record to Product_Documents.

My problem is that I don't understand how to add extra fields when creating the relationship.

I think I need to extend GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor and add a couple of dropdown fields.

As in

```
class GridFieldMyCustomStuff implements GridField_HTMLProvider, GridField_ActionProvider, GridField_URLHandler {
```

I can DO that and it works but I don't understand where the relation is being saved so I can make the function add the values of the dropdown fields.

How should I be doing this?

Is there some sort of "onRelationSet" hook? (I couldn't find one)